# Using grouping sets - identifying level names and eliminating certain sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table with the following structure:

```
  StoreID     StoreName    Region   Dept    Sales     month
   1           xyz         East     Phones   1000     201902
   2           pch         west     movies   3000     201902
   3           cts         west     tech      500     201902
   4           xyz         east     cars      8000    201902
```

Instead of writing individual union all queries to aggregate data at each level, we can do it easily in grouping sets. Especially if # of columns in table is huge and if we have to write multiple group bys.

with the union all - I would do:

```
 select month,'Store' as Level,'N/A' as store 'N/A' as Region,'N/A' as dept, sum(sales)
 from stores
 group by month
 union all
 select month,'Region' as Level,'N/A' as store,region as Region,'N/A' as dept, sum(sales)
 from stores
 group by month,region
  union all
 select month,'StoreRegion' as Level,store as store,region as Region,'N/A' as dept, sum(sales)
 from stores
 group by month,store,region
```

etc.

The same could be written in grouping sets like this:

```
select month,store,region,dept,sum(sales)
from stores
group by grouping sets (
 (month,store,region,dept)
 ,(month,store)
 ,(month,store,region)
)
```

I have 2 questions on using grouping sets:

1. How do I eliminate a particular set if I don't want it to group by it.
2. How do I add level name, Store, Region, StoreRegion etc?

I tried using grouping_id but it is not fool proof. So wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: What's wrong with the `grouping` function?

Comment: Grouping function is great - nothing wrong with it. Its saving me the pain of writing 25 union all statements with around 30 cols in aggregation. Only issue I am facing is to identify the level name accurately. I do have a hack in place which works very well - but hoping for a more technical and inbuilt solution.

Comment: First, the question is two broad.  Second, what does this mean:  "How do I eliminate a particular set if I don't want it to group by it."?  I would recommend a separate question with sample data for this.  Third, this makes no sense "How do I add level name, Store, Region, StoreRegion etc?"  What is `level`?  What is `storeregion`?  You already seem to have most of the columns in the table in the query.  Once again, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Lucky I'm still not understanding how `grouping_id` would not be "accurate". It explicitly depicts which columns are being grouped and based on the combination you can identify the set its grouped on.